# Why is the contents of my handsontable not posting to the controller action?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to send the contents of my handsontable to my controller action.  The table functions fine and I managed to call the action but the object is null.  How can I post the contents of my handsontable to my controller action?  Thanks for all your help!

```
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.handsontable.full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="../../Scripts/numeral.sv-se.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="../../Content/themes/base/demo-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    var $container = $("#handsonDataTable");
    var $console = $("#handsonDataConsole");
    var $parent = $container.parent();
    var autosaveNotification;
    $container.handsontable({
        startRows: 8,
        startCols: 6,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        contextMenu: true,
   });


   var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');

   $("button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/TableData",
            data: { "data": handsontable.getData() }, //returns all cells' data
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',

            success: function (res) {
                if (res.result === 'ok') {
                    $console.text('Data saved');
                }
                else {
                    $console.text('Save error');
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $console.text('Saved.');
            }
        });
    });

 </script>

     <div id="handsonDataTable"></div>
     <div id="handsonDataConsole"></div>

     <button>Click me</button>
```

And in my controller:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;

      namespace HandsonTable.Controllers
      {
           public class HomeController : Controller
           {
              public ActionResult Index()
               {
                ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

         [HttpPost]
          public ActionResult TableData(Object tabledata)
         {

                return View();
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: `$container.handsontable({` is never closed, is it typo?

Comment: Sorry, yeah that's a typo.  It's closed and the script runs fine.  Just in the controller action I get: {datatable|{object} when I check the parameter of the DataTable action.

Comment: Does `handsontable.getData()` return proper data a sending moment? Place `console.log(handsontable.getData())` in your code and check it form console/firebug.

Comment: ...did the console.log(handsontable.getData()) and it showed the contents of my table so I guess the getData() does it's job.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help any longer, I'm not familiar with asp.net. Last question is: does `return View();` return `json` data? I mean encoded, ready to send.

Comment: Nothing returned.. In Firebug I get 500 Internal Server Error in jquery.min.js

Comment: That means the problem lays in controller. Check your web server error log.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to check my web service log.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the controller. Ajax request is okay. You will need to revise this code. Try changing it to simpler version that returns `"hello world"` or something and check if it runs (so that you won't get Error 500 with ajax). You also can ask new question related directly to your controller. I have no skills with asp.net so it's all I can suggest.

You may also find [this guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316726) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Michal...I was able to get the data to the controller as a comma delimited string like this: data: myData = { data: handsontable.getData().toString()}.So it seems like it's the format in which the data is sent that is the issue.